# How to uninstall .Net 4.0 in safe mode?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, .net-4.0

After installing .NET 4.0 started receiving BSODs right before login (Windows XP SP3). Last known good configuration doesn't work, but safe mode works. Trying to uninstall the .NET from Add/Remove Programs says that windows installer can't run in safe mode. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with the [removal tool](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/repair-remove-and-uninstall-net-framework/) that purports to remove all of the .NET files externally. I don't know if it works in safe mode, though, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Silent install, repair and uninstall command lines for the .NET Framework 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20160209223119/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/12/10011664.aspx) can help.

Answer (score 0):

To run an MSI Installer in safe mode, you'll first have to enable the msi service:

> To start Windows Installer in Safe Mode:
>
> 1. Restart your computer and press F8 before the Boot Menu or splash screen.
> 2. Open a CMD.EXE window.
> 3. Type the following commands and press Enter:
>
>    REG ADD
>      “HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal\MSIServer” /VE
>      /T REG_SZ /F /D “Service”
>
>    net start msiserver

(Taken from: [Windows: Enable MSI Service in Safe Mode](http://wbracken.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/windows-enable-msi-service-in-safe-mode/))

However, from reading some of the comments in the post, it seems that if you're running XP Home, the REG command may not be available and you'll have to manually open the Registry Editor (regedit) and edit the required keys:

> Start > Run > ‘regedit’
>
> Browse to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\
>
> Create a new folder for ‘MSIServer’ by right-clicking on either
>   ‘Minimal’ or ‘Network’ and choosing ‘New’ > ‘Key’. Enter ‘MSIServer’
>   (CaSe SeNsItIvE).
>
> Minimal is safe mode WITHOUT network support.
>
> Network is safe mode WITH network support.
>
> You’ll probably want to do this for both.
>
> Browse to the new key you just created. On the right pane, right-click
>   on the white space and choose ‘New’ > ‘String Value’ and enter
>   ‘Service’ (CaSe SeNsItIvE).
>
> You’re done. In safe mode, Start > Run > ‘services.msc’, find ‘Windows
>   Installer’ and start it. If it starts, you did everything right. If it
>   doesn’t work check for case sensitivity and that you’re in the right
>   safe mode (minimal or network).

[(Source)](http://wbracken.wordpress.com/2008/09/27/windows-enable-msi-service-in-safe-mode/#comment-16)